# How to fix suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of '=='

Tags: c++, warnings, qt-creator, compiler-warnings, parentheses

I have a code like

```
if (config_atual[6]==config_atual[7]==config_atual[8] || 
    config_atual[1]==config_atual[4]==config_atual[7] || 
    config_atual[2]==config_atual[4]==config_atual[6])
{
   if (config_atual[7]=='X')
       cout << "O Jogador ganhou!" << endl;
   else if (config_atual[7]=='O')
       cout << "O Computador ganhou!" << endl;
}
```

about a tic-tac-toe game, and whenever I try to compile this line of code, which verifies three of the win conditions (assuming indexes 0,1,2 for first line, 3,4,5 for second and 6,7,8 for last) I get this warning :

```
suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of '==' [-Wparentheses]
```

Which I don't understand. What I am doing wrong, `config_atual` is a char array that contains the present configuration of the playing board.

What does this warning mean, and how can I correct it?

Comment: `==` Cannot be chained together.

Comment: @Quimby [Sure it can.](https://ideone.com/2mwZBQ) :)

Comment: To fix, add the parentheses as suggested. 

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208831/check-to-see-if-all-variable-are-equal-to-the-same-value-in-c)

Comment: @TrebledJ Ok,yes technically correct. But not in a useful way (apart from bools), so I would say it's the same as chaining of `cout<<x<<y<<z;` or `a+b+c+d`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `config_atual[6]==config_atual[7]==config_atual[8]` is *grouped* as `(config_atual[6]==config_atual[7])==config_atual[8]`. The part in parentheses is either `true` or `false` which is implicitly converted to an `int` type (or the type of `config_atual[8]` is that's wider than an `int`) prior to a second comparison; i.e. `config_atual[8]=={1, 0}`, where I've used what's in `{}` to indicate the possibilities. That *probably* ends up as `false`.

Occasionally the chaining of `==` in this manner is useful. But in your case it isn't, and you need to write the expression in a different way;

`config_atual[6]==config_atual[7] && config_atual[7]==config_atual[8]`

is one such way.

Answer (score 3):

`==` operator in C++ doesn't work like that. It only allows two operands, which means constructions like `a == b == c` will not work as you'd expect. Rewrite the condition in a form `(a == b && b == c)` instead (and mind the parentheses).

Comment: To expand on r5ha's solution and follow user463035818 advice coding in a language is a language.  so if your trying to figure out if you have tic tac toe one could say to themselves  " if this square is equal (==) to this square and (&&) that square is equal (==) to this square then tic-tac-toe. Might not help you to look at it that way but sure helps me.  I break down the sentence in regular language then tr to apply it to coding language

Comment: In the statement ```a==b==c```, a==b returns a Boolean value, which is then compared against c. If c is some non-boolean type, and there is an implicit conversion between a bool and that type, it will be converted and then compared to c. In this case, ```a==b``` turns into a 1 or a 0, since c is a char, which is treated as an integer. That's the case on x86, at least; I think this might be undefined behavior.

Comment: @DavidDalcino: Actually you are correct on the grouping and I wasn't. Pity you didn't write this in the answers section!

Comment: Re: "mind the parentheses" -- the parentheses aren't needed. `&&` binds more tightly than `||` (just as `*` binds more tightly than `+` in arithmetic expressions), so `(a && b) || (c && d)` is no different semantically (although it's noisier) than `a && b || c && d`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
if ((config_atual[6]==config_atual[7] && config_atual[7]==config_atual[8]) ||
    (config_atual[1]==config_atual[4] && config_atual[4]==config_atual[7]) ||
    (config_atual[2]==config_atual[4] && config_atual[4]==config_atual[6]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (((config_atual[6]==config_atual[7])==config_atual[8]) || 
    ((config_atual[1]==config_atual[4])==config_atual[7]) || 
    ((config_atual[2]==config_atual[4])==config_atual[6]))
{
   if (config_atual[7]=='X')
       cout << "O Jogador ganhou!" << endl;
   else if (config_atual[7]=='O')
       cout << "O Computador ganhou!" << endl;
}
```