# Why is 'if(1 == 1 == 1 == 1 == 1);' TRUE but 'if(-1 == -1 == -1 == -1 == -1);' FALSE?

Tags: c++, if-statement, short-circuiting

```
if (1 == 1 == 1 == 1 == 1)
    std::cout << "right";
```

The code above shows 'right'.

```
if (-1 == -1)
    std::cout << "right";
```

The code above also shows 'right'.

```
if (-1 == -1 == -1)
    std::cout << "right";
```

The code above shows nothing. (It's because the `if statement` isn't TRUE I guess?)

I would like to know why this weird thing happens.

Because `-1` is equal to `-1` and this statement is always TRUE no matter how many times I repeat (as far as I know).

Comment: think about what `true == negative-one` will evaluate to

Comment: @M.M, same problem, but you just don't start with -1 instead. Anyway,  `-1 == -1` is `true`.  `true` is `1`. `1 == -1` is `false`

Comment: Keep in mind that, in C++, you don't write mathematical equations, but a series of statements that are evaluated one by one.

Comment: @M.M aha, now I understand. thanks!

Comment: i just upvoted all the comments! thanks to everyone!

Comment: You need to also accept an answer!

Comment: I would have been shocked if the question had been asked by @M.M .

Comment: duplicates: [Why comparing three variables together with == evaluates to false?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58271178/995714), [Two '==' equality operators in same 'if' condition are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2155280/995714), [Chaining Bool values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5939077/995714), [Check to see if all variable are equal to the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15208831/995714), [Why do most mainstream languages not support “x < y < z” syntax for 3-way Boolean comparisons?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/316969/98103)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The conditions are evaluated from left to right, hence the following conditional statement

```
if (-1 == -1 == -1)
    std::cout << "right";
```

is equivalent to

```
if (true == -1)//since -1 === -1
    std::cout << "right";
```

equivalent to

```
if (1 == -1) // true is casted to 1
    std::cout << "right";
```

equivalent to

```
if (false)
    std::cout << "right";
```

So it's normal the statement `std::cout << "right";` doesn't execute and you get nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The conditions are done in their order so:

```
-1 == -1 == -1 == -1 == -1
```

becomes

```
true == -1 == -1 == -1 (because the first -1==-1 gives true)
```

becomes

```
false == -1 == -1 (because true==-1 gives false)
```

becomes

```
false ==-1
```

becomes

```
false
```

The same thing happen with `1==1==1==1==1` because `1==true` (but not `1===true`).

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at your three examples.

`1 == 1 == 1 == 1 == 1` would be equivalent to `true == 1 == 1 == 1`, since `true == 1` is `true` (since `true` gets treated as a `1`), you'd then get `true == 1 == 1` which is then `true == 1` and finally just `true`.

In your second example, `-1 == -1`, this is simply just `true`, since obviously `-1` equals itself.

Now, for your last example, you have `-1 == -1 == -1`, which becomes `true == -1`. `true` is not equal to `-1` since `1` is not equal to `-1`, so this is therefore false. As a result, the `"right"` does not get printed.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ the evaluation order of the equality operator `==` is from left to right:

```
(-1 == -1) == -1
```

is evaluated to

```
1 == -1
```

which returns false

Answer (score 0):

Your code hits on the rules for casting between `int` and `bool`.

1. Comparisons between `int` objects return a `bool`.
2. Comparisons between an `bool` and an `int` upcasts the `bool` to an `int`.

   - `false` cast to `int` is `0`
   - `true` cast to `int` is usually `1`

Your code does (1) for the first comparison and (2) for all comparisons after.

So, if we write your condition and evaluate it step by step:

```cpp
(1 == 1)   // == ... == 1
(true)     // == ... == 1
int(true)  // == ... == 1
1          // == ... == 1
true
```

versus if you compare -1:

```cpp
(-1 == -1)   // == ... == -1
(true)       // == ... == -1
int(true)    // == ... == -1
1            // == ... == -1
false
```